# "create new theme font" in powerpoint slide master using vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2016

in powerpoint's slide master view, there is a "customize fonts" option which opens a window called "create new theme fonts". using that, one can set default heading/body fonts for latin/complex scripts.
what is the equivalent vba code for this?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the

- [Master.TextStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.master.textstyles) property:

  > Returns a TextStyles collection that represents three text styles — title text, body text, and default text — for the specified slide master.
- [PpTextStyleType Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.pptextstyletype), specifically `ppBodyStyle` and `ppTitleStyle`.

Modifying the code example provided under the `Master.TextStyles` property:

```
Sub CustomizeFonts()
    Dim i As Integer

    With ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.TextStyles(ppBodyStyle)
        For i = 1 To .Levels.Count
            With .Levels(i).Font
                .Name = "Garamond"
            End With
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

And something similar to modify the heading, replacing `ppBodyStyle` with `ppTitleStyle`.

Comment: Nice one!  And ppDefaultStyle sets the defaults for text in text boxes/shapes other than Title and Body text placeholders.